# Windows keep resizing by them selfs in Fedora 21 VM Virtualbox, host Fedora 21

Tags: fedora, virtualbox, application, settings, bugs

It's really annoying but I've been getting this behaviour lately in my test machine: Fedora 21 x86_64 KDE VM in VirtualBox the host is Fedora 21.

Here is a pic:
[image]

I put the system to saved mode if I turn it off and when the VM is started everything looks normal(normally few windows/applications open) but then I fire up one or two applications and they are all much larger then my settings, all applications after this are larger then before it's no particular application.

Does anyone here know what the problem is. I've tried to fiddle with settings and Application Appearence but can't find whats wrong. Frankly I don't know what to look for.

I've looked in bugzilla for "Applications resizing" and "Windows changing size" but nothing there about this behaviour.